# Multiple dynamic subdomains and SSL (*.*.mysubdomain.mydomain.com)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain, domains

I have a requirement to add SSL to a system that uses multiple dynamic subdomains. For example:

Y.X.mysubdomain.mydomain.com
Z.X.mysubdomain.mydomain.com

X = is the name of client and is dynamic
Y & Z = are names of the clients customers and are dynamic

I've looked at wild cards however they only go one level deep (*.mysubdomain.mydomain.com) and I need a way of doing *.*.mysubdomain.mydomain.com

If there is a way of doing unlimited subdomains of a base domain that would be an option also (*.*.*.mydomain.com)

I've had a look at http://www.digicert.com/unified-communications-ssl-tls.htm however it seems you need to supply them with the subdomains and domains upfront. As these subdomains are dynamic and user generated this is not an option.

Any help or pointers would be most gratefully welcome.

Comment: I think a.b.mydomain.com will match on *.myadmain.com. At least in DNS. Not sure

Answer (score 0):

You just need a wildcard certificate for *.mydomain.com - this should be enough. Take a look at this option - http://www.digicert.com/welcome/wildcard-plus.htm for instance.

Comment: Thanks for this, however from what I can tell I would need to add the subdomains to the Subject Alternative Names list and with them being dynamiclly created and removed I still don't see this working.

Comment: also add the certificate, key and if needed ca certificate for each such subdomain created in their respective configuration in such case. That should do the workaround.

Comment: @LogicWreck A wildcard can't apply to more than one level of subdomain.